# Clipping a value to an interval

Tags: actionscript-3

In ActionScript 3, is there a shorter way to clip a value to be between 0 and 255?

```
value = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, value))
```

Comment: Thats my old answer for checking values between others : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864858/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-between-two-other-numbers-in-actionscript-3/7864948#7864948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something fast, the following will do:

```
k = (k | -int(k > 256)) & -int(k > 0) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: while I agree it's the most efficient way, it's not really an answer to the question...

Comment: Right. I was just checking if there might be something like Math.clip(0, 255, value) or other way, but since there wasn't I accepted the answer that I felt contributed the most.

Answer (score 1):

Nope,  you could create your own shortcut function easily enough though:

```
function clip(val:Number, min:Number, max:Number):Number {
    return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, val));
}
```